A question on essentially self-adjoint differential operators of the type $\Delta=D^{\ast}D$
Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth (connected, complete, oriented) Riemannian manifold and let $D:C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ be a linear partial differential operator, which I view as an operator in $L^{2}(M)$ with dense domain $C^{\infty}_{c}(M)$, i.e.
$$D:C^{\infty}_{c}(M)\to L^{2}(M).$$
Let us denote its formal adjoint by $D^{t}:C^{\infty}_{c}(M)\to L^{2}(M)$. Last but not least, I am defining the operator
$$\Delta=D^{t}D:C^{\infty}_{c}(M)\to L^{2}(M).$$
If you want to think about an example, take $d$ to be the exterior derivative of functions in which case $\Delta$ is the (Hodge) Laplacian of functions. But my question is more general. In my particular case, the operators $D$ and $D^{t}$ do not fit nicely into any complex for instance.
Now, lets say someone is interested to prove that $\Delta$ is essentially self-adjoint. The usual strategy for such questions, for example applied in Gaffney's original proof on essentially self-adjointness of the Hodge Laplacian, is to show that the $L^{2}$-closures of $D$ and $D^{t}$ are proper $L^{2}$-adjoints in the Hilbert space sense, or equivalently, to show that $D_{\mathrm{min}}=D_{\mathrm{max}}$ where $D_{\mathrm{min}}:=\overline{D}$ denotes the minimal and $D_{\mathrm{max}}:=(D^{t})^{\ast}$ the maximial closed extension. Then, it remains to show that $\overline{\Delta}=D^{\ast}\overline{D}$.
But in my case, I am interested somehow in the other way round:

Using the notation from above, if I know that $\Delta$ is essentially self-adjoint, does it follow that $D_{\mathrm{min}}=D_{\mathrm{max}}$?

If $\Delta$ is essentially self-adjoint, I know that $\overline{\Delta}=D^{\ast}D_{\mathrm{min}}=\overline{D^{t}}D_{\mathrm{max}}$, but this alone is not enough to prove the claim it seems.

If $A$ is any closed densely defined operator, then $A^*A$ is self-adjoint (due to von Neumann, I believe).

@ChristianRemling Sure, this is of course obvious. But as my question says: I am interested in the other way round. (the precise question statement is above). More precisely: I am asking if $\Delta=D^{t}D$ is essentially self-adjoint, does this imply that $\overline{D}^{\ast}=\overline{D^{t}}$, i.e. $D_{max}=D_{min}$?
